# Recursive Summation with Conditional in Prolog

Tags: recursion, prolog

I was ask to do a program in Prolog which has to be able to do a summation of pair and odd numbers with a recursive structure. The rule has the following form:

```
sum(N,PairSum,OddSum)
```

With N as the number given as parameter. 
For Example: if N=5 then PairSum=4+2 and OddSum=5+3+1

My Code is the following

```
suma(0,0,0).
suma(N,SumPares,SumImpares) :-
   N>0,
   N1 is N -1,
   suma(N1,SumaP,SumaI),
   (  (0 is mod(N,2))
   -> SumPares is SumaP + (N-2)
   ;  SumImpares is SumaI +(N-2)
   ).
```

The code compiles successfully, it fails when i run it. For example with N=5

> suma(5,SumaPares,SumaImpares)

I get the following

> ERROR: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated ERROR: In: ERROR:
>   [12] _9750 is _9756+(2-2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After following the advices from @gusbro and inluding some others i could make to this code to work properly. The key was in the base case that was suma(2,2,1) and not suma(0,0,0). Other problem i had was my summations in the if clause were I a do N-2 and I just have to leave the N alone and not substract anything. Here is the working code:

```
 suma(2,2,1).
 suma(N,SumaPares,SumaImpares) :-
       N>0,
       N1 is N -1,
       suma(N1,SumaP,SumaI),
       ( 0 is mod(N,2) ->
            (SumaPares is SumaP + N, SumaImpares is SumaI)
         ;  (SumaImpares is SumaI +N, SumaPares is SumaP)
       ).
```

Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You should see 2 singleton warnings when consulting this code: `SumaI` and `SumI` only appear once in the body of second clause of procedure `summation/3`.

Looking at your code it seems that you wanted to use the same variable, so rename SumaI to SumI. You should now see no singleton warnings after reconsulting the code.

---

[edit after clarification]

After your edit you still have singleton warnings. Aside from typos the problem is that your conditional branch assigns one of the sum variables and leaves the other as-is. I believe you want something like this:

```
suma(0,0,0).
suma(N,SumaPares,SumaImpares) :-
   N>0,
   N1 is N -1,
   suma(N1,SumaP,SumaI),
   ( 0 is mod(N,2) -> 
        (SumaPares is SumaP + (N-2), SumaImpares=SumaI)
     ;  (SumaImpares is SumaI +(N-2), SumaPares=SumaP)
   ).
```

Comment: Sorry gusbro, that was problem of my "traslation" for this post, in the orginal code is all fine, i have already edit the post with the original code wich has that error message.

Comment: it works but with "SumaImpares is Suma" and "SumaPares is SumaP" instead of   "SumaImpares = Suma" and "SumaPares = SumaP". Although the numbers it returns are not correct, sure the calculus is not good, but at least returns something and i can prove my code. Thanks a lot. I will post the correct code when all works fine!